# Differences between ASP.NET MVC framework and Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm going to be starting a new project with ASP.NET and I would like to use some framework which speed up the process. Recently I have heard that there are two main frameworks in that platform: the MVC and the Entity framework. Are they compatibles? If not, what are your advices on what to use and why? What are they best properties?

Comment: You're comparing apples to oranges.  Did you mean ASP.NET MVC compared to WebForms? Entity Framework should be compared to Linq To Sql, not MVC.

Comment: I would disagree Apples and Oranges are both fruits, so you are realistically saying they are a variation of the same thing :P

Comment: In the same way that Asp.net mvc and entity are both frameworks :p

Comment: I didn't know. Actually I thought they had the same purpose, like they were green and red apples.

Comment: Entity is like the handler for data access , and aspnet mvc is the frame work

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't compare them. These are 2 different things.

Entity framework is ORM mapper, Asp.Net Mvc is a framework that helps building web applications.

Actually - they even aren't mutually exclusive and you can use them both together quite nicely.

Answer (score 4):

MVC is an architectural pattern to build applications; entity framework is a object relational mapping framework. Quite different animals.

And yes, they can be used together, no problem.

Comment: @Arnis - I know, just didn't want belabor the point. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: except he tagged it asp.net mvc

Answer (score 3):

ADO.NET Entity Framework is an object-relational mapping (ORM) framework for the .NET Framework.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(VS.80).aspx

Other entitty frameworks are -> LINQtoSQL, NHibernate etc.

Model–View–Controller (MVC) is an architectural pattern used in software engineering. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework

Answer (score 1):

They're different things entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Although they're different things entirely they are compatible.  I am using both frameworks on a project now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both of them into a single project.

> Entity framework is object-relational mapping (ORM) framework. It is an
>   enhancement to ADO.NET that gives developers an automated mechanism
>   for accessing & storing the data in the database.
>
> Model-View-Controller (MVC) is an architectural pattern that separates
>   an application into three main logical components: the model, the
>   view, and the controller.

Answer (score 0):

These are 2 different things as mentioned before.

Entity Framework is an ORM -> a Mapper to help you get data.

asp.net is a framework to STRUCTURE your project ,with Objects and Classes, not related to entity.